# Vue.js value not accessible

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For some reason I cannot access `this.active` in my method `delete`. What
could be wrong here?

```
data () {
    return {
      ride: { user: {}, location: {}, type: {} },
      active: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    delete ()
    {
      this.active = true;
    }
   }
```

So if I click on a button delete is triggered but if I look in vue `dev tools` active keeps false?

Comment: maybe because your setting it to `false`?
I don't see why it ever should be `true` within this code

Comment: Yeah, delete is setting it to false... So it should be false after delete triggers.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've made an edit.

Comment: But the code that I've now should work right. But it doesn't?

Comment: can you post the code that triggers the method

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have in your question works fine in this snippet. Feel free to play with this snippet, making it more like your problem code, until you are able to reproduce the problem.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: {
    one: {
      template: '#one-template',
      data() {
        return {
          ride: {
            user: {},
            location: {},
            type: {}
          },
          active: false
        }
      },

      methods: {
        delete() {
          this.active = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="one-template">
  <button @click="delete">Delete</button>
  {{active}}
</template>

<one></one>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this it might be helpful to you

```
data () {
    return {
      ride: { user: {}, location: {}, type: {} },
      active: false
    }
  },

  methods: {

    delete ()
    {
      var vm = this ;
      vm.active = false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: This will give you an error, as `methods` is a JS object